# Annotations of bound chart control VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

is it possible to display annotations to bound chart? I was able to create a bound chart but when I was trying to display an annotation, it does not work at all. below is the code I use.

```
con = ConnectDB()

        Try
            con.Open()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("WITH tempLotTracking AS(SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tblLotTracking ORDER BY LotTrackingID DESC) SELECT * FROM tempLotTracking ORDER BY LotTrackingID", con)
            da.Fill(ds, "tblLotTracking")
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            MsgBox("Error connecting to database.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "WorkWeek"
        Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "TotalIssues"

        Dim myLine As LineAnnotation = New LineAnnotation()
        myLine.Name = "myLine"
        myLine.X = 3
        myLine.Y = 3
        Chart1.Annotations.Add(myLine)

        Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("tblLotTracking")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put anchor points on your chart annotation:-

```
   myLine.AnchorX = some_value
   myLine.AnchorY = some_other_value
```

And also check you aren't doing what I did and drawing the annotation text in the background colour.

Comment: hi brian. i am not using anchor when i make this chart. does this mean that i need anchors?

Comment: I don't really know. All I can suggest is when I added these lines to my code, the annotations appeared, and without them, they didn't. The help isn't much help, either. `myLine.X gets or sets the X coordinate of an annotation`, but `myLine.AnchorX gets or sets the X coordinate to which the annotation is anchored`; I can't tell the difference between those things.